# Additional line in BarChart (Charts.js)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, chart.js

I am trying to add an horizontal line (e.g. an calculated average) through the barchart that is generated by the code below. Is there a way to cover that barchart with another canvas? Or do I have to change the "Chart.js" file to get such a line? If that is necessary what has to be changed?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="Chart.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <center>
    <h2>
    <u>Statistik</u>
    </h2>
    <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>

    <script>
        var jan = 12
        var feb = 23;
        var mar = 11;
        var apr = 65;
        var mai = 33;
        var jun = 1;
        var jul = 23;
        var aug = 0;
        var sep =0;
        var okt = 0;
        var nov =0;
        var dec = 0;

        var barChartData = {
            labels : ["Januar","Februar","März","April","Mai","Juni","Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"],
            datasets : [
            {
                label : "2014",
                fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data : [12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
            }, 
            {
                label : "2015",
                fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
                highlightFill : "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
                highlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                data : [jan,feb,mar,apr,mai,jun,jul,aug,sep,okt,nov,dec]
            }]
        }
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        var chart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
            responsive : true
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for help!

Kind regards
vonGiso

Answer (score 0):

I've created something called an overlay chart that i have added to my fork of chart.js (https://github.com/leighquince/Chart.js) that could be used in this situation. it works in the same was as a line or bar chart, only difference is you declare an extra property called `type` that can either be `'line'` or `'bar'`. Then just call `new Chart(ctx).Overlay(data)`

UPDATE: also added to the fork is now the option to pass an option called <s>stacked</s> `overlayBars` (changed the name from stacked as it was a bit misleading what it was doing) which will overlay bars in front of each other.

```js
var data = {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "My First dataset",
    //new option, barline will default to bar as that what is used to create the scale
    type: "line",
    fillColor: "rgba(120,120,120,0.2)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(120,120,120,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(120,120,120,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    data: [65, 59, 4, 81, 56, 55, 40]
  }, {
    label: "My First dataset",
    //new option, barline will default to bar as that what is used to create the scale
    type: "bar",
    fillColor: "rgba(220,20,220,1)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(220,20,220,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(220,20,220,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    data: [32, 25, 33, 88, 12, 92, 33]
  }, {
    label: "My Second dataset",
    //new option, barline will default to bar as that what is used to create the scale
    type: "bar",
    fillColor: "rgba(30,30,130,1)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(30,30,130,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(30,30,130,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",

    data: [13, 29, 22, 44, 34, 77, 10]
  }]
};
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
var chart = new Chart(ctx).Overlay(data, {
  responsive: false,
  overlayBars: true,
  datasetFill: false,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.quincewebdesign.com/cdn/Chart.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" width="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it works great! But my problem changed so that i now need to overlay two or more bar charts. Do you know any solution? With your Chart.js the bar charts are printed side by side and not one in front of another...

Comment: that's the only way chart js lets you display the bars (at the moment) but I like the idea of having bars in-front of each other, ill have a look at it as think it would be useful to have in general and i'll see about adding to my fork.

Comment: ok so i have updated my fork to include this functionality, i have placed an example in my answer

Comment: Great work! I had no problems with trying your implementation. But a mouse hover within your bar does not show the exact values of the bar any more. In your first solution this is implemented. It would be useful to compare the overlayed bars.

Comment: hmm odd, in the snippet i see all data when hovering over the bars, can you provided a fiddle where this is not the case

Comment: @vonGiso did you manage to find a case where the tooltips didn't display as ive tested a few graphs now and the tooltips always display for all bars

Comment: Yes I used your files from your github, deleted the line and now for the two bars there are no tooltips any more. But I can't say why

Comment: ah ok ill do some more testing with that

Comment: I use two bars to visualize one static value and a variable value. The last one should be shown in front of the other. If the two bars have different values the smaller one (in normal case the variable value) is shown in front of the other. But if the variable value gets higher than the static one, they change their position. Could you imagine a solution to force one bar to stay in front of the other?

Comment: if the smaller ones goes behind the larger one though you won't see it?

Comment: ok i have pushed a fix, i was being an idiot and not checking properly for the bars if the line did not exist as i always tested the overlay with both types present, should be fine for displaying tooltips now

Comment: thanks, i replaced you old files with the new one, but now i have two bars side by side. I will have a look on monday where the problem is.

Comment: i changed the api to `overlayBars` (from `stacked`) as stacked was a confusing term as the bars were not really staking. I mentioned it in the answer up above but i reckon that will be the issue if you have just taken the new build from git